# How to adjust size of tab space in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

Can we resize the tab space('\t') length in c#?

When using `\t` in string, the size of the string is too long. Am I able to resize it?

[image: Too long tab space]

Comment: You can create a custom control inheriting your control to change the tab space

Comment: What UI control are you using to display the string?

Comment: I'm using `ListViewItem.Content` to store the value

Comment: The tab character representation is controlled by the ui object that displays it, not the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The /t character in a string is a fixed character, interpreted by the output device (screen or printer) to be 'of a certain size'.